# Best way to map a 2d array for pathfinding?

Tags: c++, arrays, path-finding

I have a 2d array 100x100 that uses dimesions as x and y for a 2d terrain.
It contains one of two values, 0 for the location being blocked with an obsticle, or 1 for the location being free. 
How could one efficently create another 2d array that contains a value for how many steps from the starting point it would to reach any other point? 
So if myOtherArray[50][50] is the starting point, then it should contain value 0 and myOtherArray[50][52] should contain 2 as it's two steps away, but taking in account for the obsticles, so the steps have to count around them.

I've looked at multiple path finding alhgorhitms and all focus on finding the shortest path to a specific location and nothing resembles my problem.

Comment: "*and nothing resembles my problem*" - modify those algorithms to find the shortest paths to every single index in your matrix. For example, use Dijkstra's algorithm, but instead of specifying the start and end, draw the whole traversal graph and you are good to go

Comment: You may search for [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

Comment: You need to run your path finding algorithm, Dijkstra's for example with a different stop criteria. It should not stop when finding a "target" node. Instead it should stop when all "free" locations were "visited". For each visited location record the path length to it.